# iOS 11 disable key flicks programmatically

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ios11

iOS 11 introduced key flicks.
This feature can be disabled in the device settings under `General -> Keyboard`

My question is if key flicks can also be disabled programmatically on a `UITextField`, just like spell checking for example.

I can't find the option in interface builder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it seems that is only a feature of the iOS11, not for developers.
There is no one news on the developer portal.

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same result. It seems like this cannot be configured, at least not with iOS 11.0.3
Maybe in some future release...